# Finding the previous non-zero value from an date-ordered list

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am running MS-SQL Server 2008 R2
I have a table with a similar setup as below.  There are dates in which the price is 0; however its a placeholder meaning the price from the previous month has not changed.  Can I use Coalesce or another function that will use closest PREVIOUS date's Price-value which is not zero?

**Item Name  |     Date    |   Price    **

```
Item1    |  01/01/2013 | 10.00
Item1    |  02/01/2013 | 9.50
Item1    |  03/01/2013 | 0
Item1    |  04/01/2013 | 9.50
Item1    |  05/01/2013 | 8.00
Item1    |  06/01/2013 | 8.00
Item1    |  07/01/2013 | 6.00
Item1    |  08/01/2013 | 6.00
Item1    |  09/01/2013 | 0
Item2    |  01/01/2013 | 50.00
Item2    |  02/01/2013 | 45.00
Item2    |  03/01/2013 | 35.00
Item2    |  04/01/2013 | 30.00
Item2    |  05/01/2013 | 25.00
Item2    |  06/01/2013 | 0
Item2    |  07/01/2013 | 10.00
Item2    |  08/01/2013 | 0
Item2    |  09/01/2013 | 0
```

desired output
  **Item Name  |     Date    |   Price    **

```
Item1    |  01/01/2013 | 10.00
Item1    |  02/01/2013 | 9.50
Item1    |  03/01/2013 | 9.50
Item1    |  04/01/2013 | 9.50
Item1    |  05/01/2013 | 8.00
Item1    |  06/01/2013 | 8.00
Item1    |  07/01/2013 | 6.00
Item1    |  08/01/2013 | 6.00
Item1    |  09/01/2013 | 6.00
Item2    |  01/01/2013 | 50.00
Item2    |  02/01/2013 | 45.00
Item2    |  03/01/2013 | 35.00
Item2    |  04/01/2013 | 30.00
Item2    |  05/01/2013 | 25.00
Item2    |  06/01/2013 | 25.00
Item2    |  07/01/2013 | 10.00
Item2    |  08/01/2013 | 10.00
Item2    |  09/01/2013 | 10.00
```

Comment: No, `COALESCE` on it's own won't help here. Is there ALWAYS a previous date? Is there a maximum number of continuous rows that can be zero? Unfortunately you can't just join to the previous row because it might also be zero.... so you need to join to the row before that etc... Is the figure actually a 'change' or an absolute value? i.e. are just trying to find a running total regardless of whether it is zero or not?

Comment: There should not be a time when the first value of any item is zero because each item must start with a price; so in that regard, there should always be at least one non-zero value that can be referenced.
There is no limit on the number of continuous rows that can be zero however.  
The type of value in price is a float and will likely have some characters right of the decimal point

Comment: So, does the value '10.00' mean that the price has changed by 10, or does it mean the price _is_ 10?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is you sample table

```
SELECT * INTO #TEMP
FROM
(
SELECT 'Item1' [Item Name],      '01/01/2013' [Date], 10.00 [Price]
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Item1',      '02/01/2013', 9.50
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Item1',      '03/01/2013', 0
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Item1',      '04/01/2013', 7.50
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Item1',     '05/01/2013', 0.00
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Item1',     '06/01/2013', 0.00
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Item1',     '07/01/2013', 11.00
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Item2',      '01/01/2013', 0.00
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Item2',     '02/01/2013', 12.00
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Item2',      '03/01/2013', 0.00
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Item2',      '04/01/2013', 0.00
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Item2',     '05/01/2013', 13.00
)TAB
```

And the result query

```
 SELECT [Item Name],[Date],
CASE WHEN [Price]=0 THEN 
    ISNULL((SELECT TOP 1 [Price]
     FROM #TEMP T2 
     WHERE CAST(T2.[Date] AS DATE)<T1.[Date] AND T1.[Item Name]=T2.[Item Name] AND T2.[Price]>0
     ORDER BY CAST(T2.[Date] AS DATE) DESC),0) 
    ELSE [Price] END [Price]
FROM #TEMP T1
```

Your result is here

[image]

Here is the working Fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/afabd/1 (If its shows any error on loading page, press RUNSQL, it will work)