# SQL Script - manipulate value based on previous non zero value

Tags: sql, hana

I'm using HANA SQL script and after computation my data in the view/table has displayed as below

```
Col A       Col B       Col C
1000042965  20090830    15.9
1000042965  20090906    0
1000042965  20090913    0
1000042965  20090920    14.2
1000042965  20090927    0
1000042965  20091004    0
1000042965  20091011    14.4
1000042967  20090830    13.2
1000042967  20090906    0
1000042967  20090913    12.9
1000042967  20090920    0
1000042967  20090927    0
1000042967  20091004    11.2
1000042967  20091011    11.2
```

and my expected output as

```
Col A       Col B       Excepted Result for Col C
1000042965  20090830    15.9
1000042965  20090906    15.9
1000042965  20090913    15.9
1000042965  20090920    14.2
1000042965  20090927    14.2
1000042965  20091004    14.2
1000042965  20091011    14.4
1000042967  20090830    13.2
1000042967  20090906    13.2
1000042967  20090913    12.9
1000042967  20090920    12.9
1000042967  20090927    12.9
1000042967  20091004    11.2
1000042967  20091011    11.2
```

I just want to return the previous not null values. I tried using Windows LAG
function, but my desired output is not as above.

```
LAG(col C) OVER (partition by Col A)
```

I referred the below link and try to implement the same logic, still I couldn't get 
[Finding the previous non-zero value from an date-ordered list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27435055/finding-the-previous-non-zero-value-from-an-date-ordered-list)

```
SELECT distinct col A, Col B,
CASE WHEN col C = 0 THEN 
    IFNULL(( SELECT col C
     FROM  TABLE as T2 
     WHERE CAST(T2.col B AS DATE) < T1.col B AND T1.Col A = T2.col A AND T2.Col C > 0 
     ),0)
    ELSE Col C END Col C
FROM TABLE as T1
```

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that the problem is that the subquery has no `order by` or `limit` (I think Hana SQL uses `limit`), so it can return more than one row.

The query itself is quite hard to read.  You shouldn't have spaces in column names, so something like this might work:

```
SELECT colA, ColB,
       (CASE WHEN colC = 0
             THEN IFNULL((SELECT colC
                          FROM TABLE T2 
                          WHERE T1.ColA = T2.colA AND
                                T2.colB < T1.colB AND
                                T2.ColC > 0 
                          ORDER BY T2.COLB DESC
                          LIMIT 1
                         ), 0)
             ELSE ColC
        END) as ColC
FROM TABLE T1
```

Comment: Hi Gordon, I can't use ORDER BY function in the sub query select, I get the error message as "correlated subquery cannot have TOP or ORDER BY:"

Comment: Hi Team, any help on this issue?